# converting cookies into sessions without javascript

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I want to use a cookie to create a session where it expires when the user closes the browser window. All of the posts online says the way to do so is to remove the expires attribute from the cookie. But I tried to do that and that did not work.

I have the following cookie string:

```
example=true;path=/
```

Note that I did not set the expires attribute.

What happens is that the expires attribute gets set to 1 year from now.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this cookie with `expires=0`.

Comment: How exactly are you setting this cookie?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_set_cookie_params($expire, $path, $domain, $secure, true);

// Open
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example', false, false);

// Locked Down
session_set_cookie_params('o, /forums', 'www.example.com', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true)
```

Comment: I'm using javascript

Comment: You said that "without javascript"